# ajax() method in jquery returns null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, null

I'm trying to make a very simple query:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajaxfunc.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        alert(data.resp);
    }
});
```

And in ajaxfunc.php I have

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("resp"=>"1")); ?>
```

But for a strange reason data is always null and data.resp is undefined.

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this working in my system.

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: "b.php",
    async:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
    alert(data.resp);
}
});

                       });
</script>
```

b.php

```
<?php 

$k['resp'] = 66;
echo json_encode($k);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the content type in PHP.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

When you set `dataType: 'json'` in jQuery, it atually expects JSON content from the server.

Comment: @Dmitry: What does your browser display if you got to `ajaxfunc.php` directly?

Comment: @Dmitry: Looks good. Now if there is nothing wrong with your Content-Type header, then I don't know what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

$data->resp = 1;
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```